# Combining plots with common legend to show only one legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having three plots like this:

```
df <- data.frame(stock = c("google", "google", "amazon", "amazon", "amazon", "yahoo", "yahoo", "yahoo"), status = c("open", "close", "open", "buy", "close", "open", "buy", "close"), category = c("daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily"), price = c(330379.36, 52324.62, 545240.22, 192574.83, 46721.34, 477658.62, 146724.44, 42721.78))
```

plot1:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(df,8 aes(fill=stock, y=reorder(price, status), x= status)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  ggtitle("Daily") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0, hjust=0)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=price), position = position_dodge(width= 1), vjust=0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#492ecb",  "#5041ae", "#ff53aa"))
```

plot2:

```
plot2 <- ggplot(df,8 aes(fill=stock, y=reorder(price, status), x= status)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  ggtitle("Daily") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0, hjust=0)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=price), position = position_dodge(width= 1), vjust=0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#492ecb",  "#5041ae", "#ff53aa"))
```

plot3:

```
plot3 <- ggplot(df,8 aes(fill=stock, y=reorder(price, status), x= status)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  ggtitle("Daily") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0, hjust=0)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=price), position = position_dodge(width= 1), vjust=0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#492ecb",  "#5041ae", "#ff53aa"))
```

and adding them into one plot:

```
plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot3, ncol=3, nrow=1)
```

How can it be possible to have the legend appear only once? The legend is based on the fill aesthetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, if the issue is having too many legends (so there will not be conflict with using `fill` for the plots):

```
library(patchwork)

plot1+plot2+plot3+plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

[image]